# parallel running a mpi subroutine

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I got a MPI program written by other people.

Basic structure is like this

```
program basis

initialize MPI

do n=1,12

    call mpi_job(n)  

end do 

finalize MPI

contains

subroutine mpi_job(n)  !this is mpi subroutine
.....
end subroutine

end program
```

What I want to do now is to make the do loop a parallel do loop. So if I got a 24 core machine, I can run this program with 12 `mpi_job` running simultaneously and each `mpi_job` uses 2 threads. There are several reasons to do this, for example, the performance of `mpi_job` may not scale well with number of cores. **To sum up, I want to make one level of MPI parallelization into two levels of parallelization.**

I found myself constantly encounter this problem when I working with other people.**The question is what is the easiest and efficient way to modify the program?**

Comment: Don't want to nitpick, but I assume you meant **rank** (or **process**) when you wrote "each `mpi_job` uses 2 **threads**". This is a huge difference. When you actually want to use thread parallelism within the `mpi_job`, this becomes an entirely different broad question about Hybrid Parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

> So if I got a 24 core machine, I can run this program with 12 mpi_job running simultaneously and each mpi_job uses 2 threads.

I wouldn't do that. I recommend mapping MPI processes to NUMA nodes and then spawning k threads where there are k cores per NUMA node.

> There are several reasons to do this, for example, the performance of mpi_job may not scale well with number of cores.

That's an entirely different issue. What aspect of `mpi_job` won't scale well? Is it memory bound? Does it require too much communication?

Answer (score 1):

You use should use sub-communicators.

- Compute `job_nr = floor(global_rank / ranks_per_job)`
- Use `MPI_COMM_SPLIT` over the `job_nr`. This creates a local to be used communicator for each job
- Pass the resulting communicator to the `mpi_job`. All communication then should use that communicator and the rank local to that communicator.

Of course, this all implies that there is no dependencies between the different calls to mpi_job - or that you map that to appropriate global/world communicator.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion here over the basics of what you are trying to do. Your skeleton code *will not* run 12 MPI jobs at the same time; each MPI process that you create will run 12 jobs sequentially.

What you want to do is run 12 MPI processes, each of which calls mpi_job a single time. Within mpi_job, you can then create 2 threads using OpenMP.

Process and thread placement is outside the scope of the MPI and OpenMP standards. For example, ensuring that the processes are spread evenly across your multicore machine (e.g. each of the 12 even cores 0, 2, ... out of 24) and that the OpenMP threads run on even and odd pairs of cores would require you to look up the man pages for your MPI and OpenMP implementations. You may be able to place processes using arguments to mpiexec; thread placement may be controlled by environment variables, e.g. KMP_AFFINITY for Intel OpenMP.

Placement aside, here is a code that I think does what you want (I make no comment on whether it is the most efficient thing to do). I am using GNU compilers here.

```
user@laptop$ mpif90 -fopenmp -o basis basis.f90
user@laptop$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
user@laptop$ mpiexec -n 12 ./basis
 Running           12  MPI jobs at the same time
 MPI job            2 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job           11 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job           11 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job            8 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job            0 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job            0 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job            2 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job            8 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job            4 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job            4 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job           10 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job           10 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job            3 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job            3 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job            1 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job            1 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job            5 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job            5 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job            9 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job            9 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job            7 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
 MPI job            7 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job            6 , thread no.            1  reporting for duty
 MPI job            6 , thread no.            0  reporting for duty
```

Here's the code:

```
program basis

  use mpi

  implicit none

  integer :: ierr, size, rank
  integer :: comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD

  call MPI_Init(ierr)

  call MPI_Comm_size(comm, size, ierr)
  call MPI_Comm_rank(comm, rank, ierr)

  if (rank == 0) then
     write(*,*) 'Running ', size, ' MPI jobs at the same time'
  end if

  call mpi_job(rank)

  call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

contains

  subroutine mpi_job(n)  !this is mpi subroutine

    use omp_lib

    implicit none

    integer :: n, ithread

    !$omp parallel default(none) private(ithread) shared(n)

    ithread = omp_get_thread_num()

    write(*,*) 'MPI job ', n, ', thread no. ', ithread, ' reporting for duty'

    !$omp end parallel

  end subroutine mpi_job

end program basis
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, but thread placement is actually part of OpenMP 4.0 and later.

Comment: Thank you very much for a complete working code. I always want to know how to hybrid mpi and openmp. But the openmp part of your code seems doesn't acquire the correct thread number automatically on cpu with hyper thread. For example, my computer has i7 6700 which has 4 physical cores and 8 threads. However, for parallel computing, we should use only 4 physical cores. While `mpiexec -n 2 a.exe` output 2 mpi process and each with 4 openmp threads.